# How to close the Accessibility recorded gesture feature once finished?

Tags: ios, accessibility

How do you stop a favorite recorded "gesture" once you are done using it?  I am working with patients who have severe fine motor skills deficits.  They must use a stylus to work on an iPad or iPhone.

The recorded gesture function in the accessibility settings would be helpful if we could get it to stop, or go away, once we have finished using it.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just press the AssistiveTouch button to show the panel, then close it again by tapping outside.